# how much the number of dbi affects the RSSI value?

Tags: wireless-networking, antenna

I would like to connect to a public hotspot but it's far from my house: I analysed the open network through airodump-ng utility and saw the RSSI value is only -90.

I wonder if it's worthwhile to buy a powerful antenna (56 dbi or higher) and try to connect to the hotspot and surf normally (as if it was a home 6 mega adsl):

how and how much the dbi value of an antenna affects the RSSI value of the networks?

Comment: RSSI is a relative value, not an absolute one, which can also vary by manufacturer, meaning there is no universal standard, and antenna are rated in +XdBi gain (an absolute value)... So the answer is we don't know and can't really answer this question, or even speculate with any confidence. If you mean that the signal you are seeing is -90dBm, then to get a really good signal (-70dBm or higher) you would need an increase of 20dB or more, this would require a grid or parabolic antenna, similar to the ones at the bottom of the page here: http://www.radiolabs.com/products/wireless/wireless.html

Answer (score 2):

If your antenna really gets 56dBi of directional gain at 2.4 or 5GHz, then it is a highly focused directional antenna and must be pointed very accurately. In theory it would actually add 56dB to your link budget if you can get it pointed correctly, but you might lose some of that due to cable loss in your longer coax cable, and also when wind shakes your mast.

Also note that this is based on clear line of sight. You can find illustrations online about how much clearance you need around your line of sight to make this work well.

And, by the way, 56dBi sounds like a BS claim. I doubt you'll find a reputable antenna vendor claiming anything above about 30dBi. There are a lot of disreputable antenna products out there that make ridiculous claims and prey on people people desperate for better long range Wi-Fi links that don't know RF engineering well enough to know better.

Comment: Yep, the antenna claim sounds like fertilizer. And then there's putting all that money into hardware for "free" WiFi only to find that if you become an abusive user, in the eyes of the hotspot operator, you might just get cut off anyway.